# rails select depending on another select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

i have license controller, license having user_id, product_id, version_id,
product and version having relation between them
i want to make depending select, when choosing a product the 2nd select get to me all the versions for this product

```
      <div class="field">
    <%=f.label(":product_id", "Choose product")%>
    <%=f.collection_select :product_id, Product.all, :id, :name, include_blank: true %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%=f.label(":version_id", "Choose Version")%>
    <%=f.grouped_collection_select :version_id, Product.all, :versions, :name, :id, :name, include_blank: true %>
  </div>
```

Comment: Look at http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/grouped_options_for_select

Comment: that's didn't work
the simple onchange alert function is not working even

Answer (score 0):

What I would do in this situation is I would issue an ajax call when your first select drop down changes. This ajax call would send the ID of the Product selected to a controller action where you would fetch all the versions for that Product ID. Once you get all the versions for the product you would return a js.erb view for example with the new drop down containing the collection of versions for that product. That is one way to do it, there are certainly other routes you could take.

Comment: thanks for your reply, i tried this, but in sorrow i don't know why it is not working